# I have two method calls in same line which I need to mock.How to mock it?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Below is my piece of code.

```
String domain = service.getURL().getDomain();
```

For this, I am trying to mock with the below piece of code.

```
when(serviceMock.getURL().getDomain()).thenReturn(someDomainName);
```

But it is throwing null pointer exception.

Here I am doing two different method calls. Is it possible to mock the above scenario?

Comment: You'll need two mocks here.Mock the `getURL()` to return the mocked Url and mock the `getDomain` of the mock URL

Answer (score 0):

You'll need multiple mocks here in order for the "*chained*" calls to work as I do not believe this mocking framework has auto/recursive mocking features.

Mock the `service.getURL()` to return a mocked URL object and mock the `getDomain()` of the mock URL object to behave as need.

```
//...

when(urlMock.getDomain()).thenReturn(someDomainName);
when(serviceMock.getURL()).thenReturn(urlMock);

//...
```

That way, when

```
String domain = service.getURL().getDomain();
```

Is called, it will behave as expected.